# Float left and display inline not functioning

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem that means my floating left doesn't work and removes my 10% top padding. Display inline doesn't work either it push everything to the very left. Could someone please explain what I have done wrong? Code is below.

```css
.outer {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

.galleryouter {
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.gallerypicture {
  width: 100%;
}

.galleryname {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallerydesc {
  width: 100%;
}

.galleryprice {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallerysold {
  width: 100%;
}

.galleryamount {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<?php
    if (isset ($_SESSION['Email']))
    {
 echo "";

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>


  <br/>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="galleryouter" align="center">
      <div class="gallerypicture">
        <img src=<?php echo $row[ "picture"]; ?> width="50%">
        <br/>
        <div class="galleryname">
          <h1>
            <?php echo"'"; echo $row["Name"]; echo"'"; ?>
          </h1>
          <div class="gallerydesc">
            <p>
              <?php echo $row["Description"]; ?> </p>
            <div class="galleryamount">
              <p>
                <?php echo $row["Amount"]; ?> </p>
              <div class="gallerycost">
                <p>
                  <?php echo"£"; echo $row["Cost"]; ?> </p>
                <div class="gallerysold">
                  <p>
                    <?php echo $row["sold"]; ?> </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting (.galleryamount, .gallerysold, etc) to width:100%. It is expanding to 100% of the container, meaning it is impossible to display those inline. Remove those widths.

Comment: I've tried that but that sizing is only making it 100% of the div that the other divs are in (galleryamount etc). All the .gallery parts are inside of a div called .galleryouter and then inside another div called outer so it should just be measuring up to .outer and .galleryouter (30%)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I managed to work it out. The div that everything was inside of didn't have a specified width (I forgot about it)